# ssh remote command with zsh: zsh:1: no matches found

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, zsh

I am writing a script to zip some file on remote server and then transfer it.
I got the error with remote ssh command and wildcard like that

```
ssh 1.2.3.4 "ls /home/lhc/*.txt"
zsh:1: no matches found: /home/lhc/*.txt
```

I searched and found that it may caused by a mechanism named globing, but I cannot get rid of it.
I tried:

1. run script with bash
2. adding noglob either before ssh or before ls
3. adding bash -c before ls
4. put single quote and backslash at multiples locations

None of them work. I got either the same error, or no error but no file is picked up.

Comment: The author wrote: `I put the wrong server address and therefore connected to another server. The error happened because the file truly doesn't exist.` I’m voting to close this question because questions describing a problem that went away when a typo was fixed are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question. I put the wrong server address and therefore connected to another server. The error happened because the file truly doesn't exist.

Comment: `Please ignore this question.` – I believe you can delete the question.